# Transform timestamped messages recorded in a bag file using tf messages

Tags: ros, python

I have a `.bag` which contains recorded messages on topics `/topic1` and `/topic2`. The messages have `/world` as `frame_id`, so both of the messages associated with these topics are stamped, i.e. they have a header.

The same `.bag` file also contains recorded messages on the topic `/tf` (of type [`tf2_msgs/TFMessage`](http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/geometry_msgs/html/msg/TransformStamped.html)). These transform messages have the `frame_id` set to `/world` and the `child_frame_id` set to the local frames associated with the IMUs from which the messages are being sent over respectively topic `/topic1` and `/topic2`.

Now, I need the messages sent over the `/topic1` and `/topic2` to be converted to their corresponding local frame (i.e. the child frame or `child_frame_id` ) from the (fixed) frame `/world`. Since both the `/tf` messages and the messages of the topics `/topic1` and `/topic2` are stamped, I thought we could do this without much trouble, but I'm not sure since I'm very new to ROS.

I've looked around for various solutions, but I didn't find an exact solution for my problem, maybe because I didn't recognize it as such, given my limited knowledge of ROS, as I said.

I would appreciate a step by step description of the approach and, if you don't want to write a full solution with code (preferably in Python), at least point me to the similar examples. Please, do not suggest me to read the tutorials of `/tf`, I've partially done it, and it didn't help much.

Comment: It may be easier to answer your question if you edited it to provide details of what you actually want to achieve (why you want those topics converted to the local frame), what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see.

Comment: This question is pretty old but, in case the OP comes back, we would need to know the message types being published on `/topic1` and `/topic2` to help with transforms. Knowing that messages are being published in the "`/world`" frame and wanting to transform them to a different frame doesn't help if we don't know /what/ we're transforming.

Answer (score 1):

As far I understand, you have a topic `/topic` and an associated transformation on the tf topic. You then want to move the pose according to the tf transformation.

TF provides you with a tree representing all the transformations and the changes in time. It's really useful for easily tracking the position of each sensor on the robot for example. By knowing the transformation of each sensor to the base of the robot, you only need to change the transformation between the world and the base of the robot to know the position of all sensors in space.

If you want to transform `/topic` to its actual pose in tf, you'll need first to read the [transformation from the tf topic](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20%28C%2B%2B%29) from `frame_id` to `child_frame_id`. Then apply this transformation to the pose in `topic` at the same time. An efficient way to get messages at the same time is to use [message filter](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters). I'm sure you'll find plenty of example to do just that, for example [here](http://wiki.ros.org/message_filters#Time_Synchronizer).

Answer (score 1):

In general terms, transforms between coordinate frames in ROS are achieved through the [tf](http://wiki.ros.org/tf) API. Strictly speaking we should actually use [tf2](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2), but since its documentation still has [some catch up to do](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/tf2_ros/html/python/tf2_ros.html) you might want to stick to tf for the time being.

The [Python tf API](http://docs.ros.org/api/tf/html/python/index.html) makes it easy to convert geometric messages between coordinate frames. Following the scenario you outlined, converting IMU data from global to local coordinate frames could be done as below:

```
import rospy
import tf

import sensor_msgs.msg
import geometry_msgs.msg

class IMUListener(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tf_listener = tf.TransformListener()
        self.global_frame = rospy.get_param('~global_frame', 'world')
        self.subscriber = rospy.Subscriber('imu', sensor_msgs.msg.Imu, self.callback, queue_size=1)

    def callback(self, imu):
        global_frame = self.global_frame
        local_frame = imu.header.frame_id

        if not (self.tf.frameExists(global_frame) and self.tf.frameExists(local_frame)):
            rospy.logerr('Could not transform between frames "%s" and "%s"' % (global_frame, local_frame))
            return

        # Build a stamped quaternion message containing the IMU orientation readings,
        # timestamp and source reference frame (presumed to be the global reference frame).
        reading = geometry_msgs.msg.QuaternionStamped()
        reading.header.seq = imu.header.seq
        reading.header.stamp = imu.header.stamp
        reading.header.frame_id = global_frame
        reading.quaternion = imu.orientation

        # Convert the input quaternion from its source frame (taken from header.frame_id)
        # to the given target frame, using the transform available at time header.stamp.
        transformed = self.tf_listener.transformQuaternion(local_frame, reading)

        print transformed
```

This code assumes that your problem is that even though IMU messages are assigned the sensor's frame id, the actual readings are relative to the global frame, and therefore you need a way to convert them to the right reference. It uses a `tf.TransformListener` object to listen to messages in the `/tf` topic and extract time-stamped transforms between coordinate frames. The method `transformQuaternion()` transforms the input `QuaternionStamped` message from its assigned `header.frame_id` reference frame to the target frame, using the transform between source and target frames that was in effect at time `header.stamp`.